# Mkvirtualenv: command not found 19.04

Tags: python3, pip, django, virtualenvwrapper

Trying to install `Django Framework`. This when I am trying to activate an virtual environment for the very first time:

```
mkvirtualenv test
mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

Location of the installation:

```
which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Update from research 
I didn't use `sudo` when installing.
Here is [tutorial one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment) and [tutorial two.](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: can you provide a link to the tutorials you followed!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to change the command to `mkdir` and follow different steps.

Answer (score 1):

you use python3, but virtualenv uses python2 by default. So you need to modify it.

Add the following sentence at the end of the '~/.bashrc',to modify the default python and configure virtualenv：

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=~/.environments
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and then reload this configuration file with the command：

```
source ~/.bashrc
```